# ilterate through html elements with specific id with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following piece of phtml code:

```
<div id='calendar'>
<?php foreach($eventCollection as $event) { ?>
    <div id="<?php echo $event['id']?>">
        <div class="title" data-mage-init="<?php echo $event['title']?>"></div>
        <div class="start" data-mage-init="<?php echo $event['start']?>"></div>
        <div class="end" data-mage-init="<?php echo $event['end']?>"></div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

`$event['id']` is a series of incrementing integer from 0. Now I want to write some jQuery code that find the element of id `calendar`, then iterate through `div` elements with the integer id and get the value of `data-mage-init` and put them in an array. Is that doable?

Comment: So you don't know the name of ID selector to select with?

Comment: no, my ID incrementing in a iteration

Comment: Check my answer. You can get your dynamic `id` and `data-mage-init` value in the result array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below. You can iterate through 1 level nested `DIV` inside `#calendar` and then again loop through each individual div inside that and build your array.

**HTML**

```
<div id='calendar'>
    <div id="0">
        <div class="title" data-mage-init="first"></div>
        <div class="start" data-mage-init="first start"></div>
        <div class="end" data-mage-init="first end"></div>
    </div>
     <div id="1">
        <div class="title" data-mage-init="second"></div>
        <div class="start" data-mage-init="second start"></div>
        <div class="end" data-mage-init="second end"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="2">
        <div class="title" data-mage-init="third"></div>
        <div class="start" data-mage-init="third start"></div>
        <div class="end" data-mage-init="third end"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    var result = [];
    $( "#calendar > div" ).each(function() {
      var myObj = {};
        var $el = $(this);
      myObj['id'] = $el.attr('id');
      myObj['data'] = [];
      $el.find('div').each(function() {
          myObj['data'].push($(this).attr('data-mage-init'));
      });
      result.push(myObj);
    });
    console.log(result);
});
```

NOTE: Result will be something like: `[Object { id="0",  data=[3]}, Object { id="1",  data=[3]}, Object { id="2",  data=[3]}]`

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this
var arr=[];$("#calendar div").each(function(){
var obj=new Object();
obj.ID=$(this).attr('id');
obj.title=$(this).find(".title").attr('data-mage-init');
obj.start=$(this).find(".start").attr('data-mage-init');
obj.end=$(this).find(".end").attr('data-mage-init');
arr.push(obj);
});
```

Comment: I think we have to add some conditional here, as `each` will go through one `div` at a time, not 4 of them.

Answer (score 0):

Let replace my html with your php array code. And also try to use **class** attribute along with **id**.
Try this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="1" class="test">
    <div class="title" data-mage-init="title1"></div>
    <div class="start" data-mage-init="start1"></div>
    <div class="end" data-mage-init="end1"></div>
</div>
<div id="2" class="test">
    <div class="title" data-mage-init="title2"></div>
    <div class="start" data-mage-init="start2"></div>
    <div class="end" data-mage-init="end2"></div>
</div>
<div id="3" class="test">
    <div class="title" data-mage-init="title3"></div>
    <div class="start" data-mage-init="start3"></div>
    <div class="end" data-mage-init="end3"></div>
</div>
<div id="4" class="test">
    <div class="title" data-mage-init="title4"></div>
    <div class="start" data-mage-init="start4"></div>
    <div class="end" data-mage-init="end4"></div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var arr = new Array();
        $.each($('.test'), function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var title = $('#'+id).find('.title').attr('data-mage-init');
            var start = $('#'+id).find('.start').attr('data-mage-init');
            var end = $('#'+id).find('.end').attr('data-mage-init');
            arr.push([title, start, end]);
        });
        console.log(arr);
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: unfortunately my code must be placed in an interation

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have more than one grouping of integer ID to loop with. It is better to separate each data into their on particular parent, try below code :

**HTML** - assume have two `div` inside calendar container

```
<div id='calendar'>
  <!-- this is just for testing, for your situation should be in iteration,
       it doesn't whether you code these element in iteration,because in jQuery side 
       we use each to loop over all the elements -->
  <div id="0">
    <div class="title" data-mage-init="01"></div>
    <div class="start" data-mage-init="02"></div>
    <div class="end" data-mage-init="03"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="1">
    <div class="title" data-mage-init="11"></div>
    <div class="start" data-mage-init="12"></div>
    <div class="end" data-mage-init="13"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And **JS** should be :

```
// create empty object
var dataMageObj = {};
// find element with `calendar` ID, and fetch only it direct children
$('#calendar').children().each(function ( i, e ) {
   // define obj properties with `<div id="0">`, take only integer val
   // and assign empty array to store particular items 
   dataMageObj[e.id] = [];
   // loop over calendar's children descendant
   $( this ).children('[data-mage-init]').each(function (ii, ee) {
      // and push into array container using data-mage-init
      dataMageObj[e.id].push($(ee).data('mageInit'));
   });
});
```

Result would be like this :

```
{ 
  0 : [01, 02, 03,...], 
  1 : [11, 12, 13,...] 
}
```

And here is [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/d0wtnurn/)( *see browser console*) i could provide for you.

**Noted** : You said `$event['id']` is a series of incrementing integer from 0, thus naming the HTML id with digit is not best practice. Consider begin with a letter `([A-Za-z])` and may be followed by any number of `letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").`